# R subset based on range of dates

Tags: r, conditional-statements, subset

Say I have a data set with 3 columns, A, B and C, that contain dates for a large number of rows. How can I create a subset that omits the rows where the date in C is not within the range of the dates in A and B?

Comment: Hi Jason, Welcome to StackOverflow. Please have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and try to provide us with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Also, this kind of operation is called "subsetting" - this should help you to easily google the answer. If you fail to find anything (unlikely), *then* ask a question here (and provide us with some data and what you have tried so far).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R - check if string contains dates within specific date range](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31716187/r-check-if-string-contains-dates-within-specific-date-range)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking something like the following?

Let's say your initial dataframe is *df*, which is the following:

```
df
            A          B          C
1  2016-02-16 2016-03-21 2016-01-01
2  2016-07-07 2016-06-17 2016-01-31
3  2016-05-19 2016-09-10 2016-03-01
4  2016-01-14 2016-08-21 2016-04-01
5  2016-09-02 2016-06-15 2016-05-01
6  2016-05-09 2016-07-17 2016-05-31
7  2016-06-13 2016-06-23 2016-07-01
8  2016-09-17 2016-03-11 2016-07-31
9  2016-03-09 2016-05-13 2016-08-30
10 2016-01-20 2016-09-01 2016-09-30
```

Now if you do the following subset operation, we shall get the following dataframe subset:

```
df.sub <- df[apply(df, 1, function(x) (x[3] < min(x[1], x[2])) | 
                                      (x[3] > max(x[1], x[2]))),]
df.sub
            A          B          C
1  2016-02-16 2016-03-21 2016-01-01
2  2016-07-07 2016-06-17 2016-01-31
3  2016-05-19 2016-09-10 2016-03-01
5  2016-09-02 2016-06-15 2016-05-01
7  2016-06-13 2016-06-23 2016-07-01
9  2016-03-09 2016-05-13 2016-08-30
10 2016-01-20 2016-09-01 2016-09-30
```

Hope it helps.